# WP - API - OAuth 1.0a Server, How to implement with AngularJS?

Tags: wp-api, rest-api, oauth

I making an Angular WordPress theme and I want to add authentication to it using the `WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server` plugin, which isn't [documented](http://oauth1.wp-api.org/index.html) not very well.

I get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), But I haven't got an idea on how to implement OAuth 1.0a in my AngularJS theme. I've googled a lot but can't get any results.

So is there any Example, Article or any other resources to get the idea?